# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message using jersey 1 client

Tags: tomcat, jersey, client, weblogic

Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Comment: please share at least the log snipet with the statck trace

Comment: Hi, the log with the stack trace is in the code above. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

My client was sending the SSLHello message using SSLv2. The server accepted only TLSv1.2. Thus, the first message during the handshake was incomprehensible for the server. 
Since the client runs on weblogic 12.1.3 the following lines resolved the issue
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2